# Reading part of system file contents with PHP

Tags: php

I have a `config` file, in `etc/` called `1.conf`

Here is the contents..

```
[2-main]
exten => s,1,Macro(speech,"hi {$VAR1} how is your day going?")
exten => s,4,Macro(dial,2,555555555)
exten => s,2,Macro(speech,"lkqejqe;j")
exten => s,3,Macro(speech,"hi there")
exten => s,5,Macro(speech,"this is a test ")
exten => s,6,Macro(speech,"testing 2")
exten => s,7,Macro(speech,"this is a test")
exten => 7,1,Goto(2-tester2,s,1)
exten => 1,1,Goto(2-aa,s,1)
[2-tester]
[2-aa]
exten => 1,1,Goto(2-main,s,1)
```

How can I read the content in between speech for example..

```
exten => s,6,Macro(speech,"testing 2")
```

Just get `"testing 2"` from that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are many `speech`, which `speech` ? All ?

Comment: Theres a unique number after s, so you could pick one that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this

```
$text = file_get_contents('/etc/1.conf');
preg_match_all('/speech,"(.*)"/', $text, $match);
```

will fill the `$match` array with all the text from speech lines. Specifically, `$match[1]` will be an array containing just the string inside the quotes, so you can do this for convenience and readability:

```
$speeches = $match[1];
echo $speeches[0]; // or 1 or 2 etc.
```

Comment: Nice thank you!

How about if  its under [2-aa] instead of [2-main]? How would you do that?

Comment: That regexp matches every line containing `speech` followed by a comma and a string enclosed in double quotes, wherever it appears in the file.

Comment: Ahh I see.

So what that does it prints out "speech,"testing 2"" for me.

How would I just print out what is inbetween the "" which is testing 2?

Comment: The `$match[0]` array contains the full string found, while the `$match[1]` array contains only the value inside the quotes. Try `print_r($match)` to see its structure.

Comment: print $match[1] just prints out "Array" for me

Comment: That's because `$match[1]` is an array itself. The values are in `$match[1][0]`, `$match[1][1]`, etc.